# Python Scipy integrate.quad()

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I'm trying to solve an integral inside a for loop where the value of the integral changes with every loop.

```
Ni_1D = np.array([(x/2)*(x-1), x-x**2, (x/2)*(x+1)])
Tn= [10.0, 10.0, 10.0]
Tt=[0, 0, 0]
y_coor = [0.0, 1.25, 2.5]
x_coor = [4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
dN1D = np.array([x-.5, x-2*x, x+.5])

for i in range(3):
    def f(x):
         return Ni_1D[i]*(Tn[i]*y_coor[i]+Tt[i]*x_coor[i])* dN1D[i]
    fx[i] = integrate.quad(f,-1,1)
```

But I keep getting the error "cannot convert expression to float." Obviously something is wrong with my first input to quad.

I can't figure out how to get the correct input for f for quad(). When I paste in the function manually everything works fine. For example for i=1 f=-x*(-12.5*x**2 + 12.5*x). When I define the function direction as -x*(-12.5*x**2 + 12.5*x) everything works fine.

Comment: `Ni_1d` is built from an unknown `x`?  `dN1d`?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have included that. x is symbolic and defined using sympy:

x = sympy.symbols('x')

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Why do you think that will work in a numeric program?

Comment: Well I suppose I thought it would work because when I bypass the for loop and ask it to evaluate the integral directly it works fine. For example:

def f(x):
     return -x*(-12.5x**2 + 12.5x)
fx = integrate.quad(f,-1,1) 

works fine. If my integrand changes with each iteration I need to keep "x" as symbolic. Is there a way to evaluate the integral with a symbolic program?

Comment: With `f(x)`, `quad` calls it supplying a number as the integration variable.  The `x` in function argument is not the same as `x` used a sympy expression.  DO NOT TRY USE SYMPY WITH SCIPY.

Comment: How would you recommend I evaluate the integral then? I need to use sympy to create the integrand since it changes each loop.

Comment: Don't confuse sympy symbols with python variables.  Or sympy expressions with python functions. You are integrating 3 different functions.  Sympy can't be used to hide that.

Answer (score 2):

When code doesn't work as expected, look at the pieces. Don't assume anything.

For specific `i` value:

```
In [30]: i=1
In [31]: Ni_1D[i]*(Tn[i]*y_coor[i]+Tt[i]*x_coor[i])* dN1D[i]
Out[31]: -x*(-12.5*x**2 + 12.5*x)
```

Or wrapping that in the function:

```
In [32]: def f(x):
    ...:     return Ni_1D[i]*(Tn[i]*y_coor[i]+Tt[i]*x_coor[i])* dN1D[i]
    ...:
In [33]: f(1)
Out[33]: -x*(-12.5*x**2 + 12.5*x)
In [34]: type(_)
Out[34]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

Regardless of what argument you supply, the result is still a `sympy` `mul` object, not some number.  The `x` in the sympy expression is not the function argument.

To supply a number for a symbol in a sympy expression, you have to use `subs`.  And `quad` is not going to do that for you.

```
In [35]: f(1).subs(x,1)
Out[35]: 0
In [36]: f(1).subs(x,10)
Out[36]: 11250.0000000000
```

If you really must use sympy, use `lambdify`, for example as in

```
In [41]: def f(z):
    ...:     fn = sympy.lambdify('x',Ni_1D[i]*(Tn[i]*y_coor[i]+Tt[i]*x_coor[i])* dN1D[i]
    ...: )
    ...:     return fn(z)
    ...:
In [42]: f(10)
Out[42]: 11250.0
```

Doing the sympy lambdify every time `quad` wants a value is going to slow down the evaluation considerably.  `sympy` is not fast.